# Putting space in bat file "go to error"

Tags: batch-file

Hi i have the next code for a LARP GAME in a .bat file :P

The code works but if i put SPACES in the password the CMD window close with a goto unexpected error. Where is the error?

```
@echo off
title CONSOLA
color 0A
if "%1" neq "" ( goto %1)
pause>nul
echo Conectando... 213.226.53.12...
:A
echo BIENVENIDO A INITECH
echo INTRODUZCA EL CODIGO DE ACCESO DE EMPLEADO
set/p "pass=>"
cls
if NOT %pass%== prueba goto :FAIL
if %pass%== prueba goto :LOADING
:FAIL
echo ACCESO INCORRECTO
goto :A
:LOADING
```

Comment: A good practice for string comparisons is to enclose both operands in quotes, something like `if "%1" equ "something" ( ... )`. So you don't have to worry about spaces messing around.

Comment: But if a put:

if NOT "pass"=="prueba" goto :FAIL
if "pass"=="prueba" goto :LOADING

The gotos dont work :(

Comment: oh!

if NOT "%pass%"=="prueba" goto :FAIL
if "%pass%"=="prueba" goto :LOADING

Works! 

Thanks! so much :)